# Multi-line for stack trace in Grafana Logs dashboard?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grafana

While using the Grafana Logs Visualization (CloudWatch as log source) the error stack is hard to follow as Grafana doesn't translate the newline char.

e.g.

```
"{\"mdc\":{\"method\":\"GET\",\"path\":\"/api/my-req\",\"userId\":\"123\"},\"exception\":{\"exception_class\":\"java.text.ParseException\",\"exception_message\":\"Invalid serialized unsecured/JWS/JWE object: Missing part delimiters\",\"stacktrace\":\"java.text.ParseException: Invalid serialized unsecured/JWS/JWE object: Missing part delimiters\\n\\tat com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEObject.split(JOSEObject.java:222)\\n\\tat com.nimbusds.jose.JWSObject.parse(JWSObject.java:443)\\n\\tat co.myclass.configs.DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.getClaims(DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:107)\\n\\tat co.myclass.configs.DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.logRequestInformation(DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:59)\\n\\tat co.myclass.configs.DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.java:47)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.sendStartAuthentication(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:215)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleAccessDeniedException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:193)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:174)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:143)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\\n\\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\\n\\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:769)\\n\\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\\n\\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\\n\\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\\n\\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)\\n\\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)\\n\\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\\n\\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\\n\\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\\n\\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\\n\\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)\\n\"},\"line_number\":112,\"class\":\"co.myclass.configs.DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint\",\"@version\":1,\"source_host\":\"api-688669bf96-8pqgd\",\"message\":\"Exception while trying to get claims: [Request] 2020398429\",\"thread_name\":\"http-nio-8080-exec-9\",\"@timestamp\":\"2023-02-20T15:23:02.483+0000\",\"level\":\"WARN\",\"file\":\"DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint.java\",\"method\":\"getClaims\",\"logger_name\":\"co.myclass.configs.DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint\"}\n"
```

In Grafana, the option wrap lines doesn’t care about newlines (\n) actually present in the message, and the prettify json option just expands json fields but the log message itself (error stack) remains on a one line.

to be clearer, I’d like message like `hello\nworld` to be displayed like this:

```
    hello
    world
```

Is there any way I can translate `\n` into a new line in Grafana Logs?

Thank you for any advice that you might have

Comment: Which panel did you use?

Comment: hi @JanGaraj, I'm using the Logs panel, and it's something similar to this one https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/14109-cloudwatch-logs/

Do you know of a panel that supports newline in error stack?

Comment: Dunno, but don't use log panel. Try to use table panel, maybe + json transformation + Cell value inspect. Problem is that `\\n` is not a newline - it is espaced newline only - so you need to make real new line first. I use Loki with where I have a lot of backtraces with new lines and that perfectly human readable in my table panel with `Cell value inspect` enabled.

Comment: Is it possible to enrich the logs at the source using an encoder and layout? Similar to `ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder` and `ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout`? That might just do the trick

Answer (score 2):

In the LogQL query you need to parse your log content as JSON and then extract the `message` field by adding the following :

`| json | line_format "{{ .message }}"`

Grafana then begins unescape the newlines and quotation marks.